# No DOTNET binding support for Visual Studio 12 2013

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, cmake, messagebroker

I've been working on building the C++ Qpid messaging broker for Windows which uses the boost library and CMake to do the actual build. I ran the command `cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" C:\< home >\Downloads\qpid-cpp-0.34` as per the [install instructions for windows](https://gist.github.com/loremIpsum1771/1382a5125fd52e87268a83d28db4b5e9) and I got this [log output](https://gist.github.com/loremIpsum1771/cd3cbbb5b6ec5358b9d9e5b16a4ad9b4) at the end of which the message: `No DOTNET binding support available for Visual Studio 12 2013` appeared.

Is there a dotnet binding that has to be installed for this build to work?

Comment: Do you need this feature? Perhaps there is an option in CMake-gui to not build these bindings.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah it turns out that you can just turn off the feature. I'll post an answer from what I was told on the Apache Qpid users forum.

Comment: ***Yeah it turns out that you can just turn off the feature.*** I expected that being familiar with `CMake` however every project is different and need not follow the usual pattern..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per a response I was given on the Apache Qpid Users forum, the binding can be turned off:

> The binding is a product of the build. However, support for .NET binding ended with Visual Studio 2012. 
>   In your cmake command line turn off the .NET binding with:
>   `-DBUILD_BINDING_DOTNET=No`